# Is it true one shouldn't listen to music whilst falling asleep?

Tags: halacha, music, sleep

Does it have a source in Halacha, is it a Minhag or is it just made up?

Answer (score 4):

[The Tur](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2607) quotes Tosfos that one isn't allowed to go to sleep or wake up with music.

[R' Shlomo Zalman Aurbach](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507031528/http://revach.net/halacha/tshuvos/Rav-Shlomo-Zalman-Auerbach-Waking-Up-To-Music/4614) said that the prohibition on waking up to music still applies, so too it should apply to going to sleep with music.

Comment: I would recommend adding the locations in Tur and Halichos Shlomo to your answer, so that it will still be of use in case the links break.

Comment: "In case the link breaks" what do you mean by that?

Comment: @user8553 -- If the sites that you link to go down or change the way they are organized, providing more information, like a daf or section, will help people still find the information in the future.  For example, rather than just quoting "Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach", say "Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach - (Halichos Shlomo Tefila 13:18)".

Comment: Mind you, this was based on a Gemara about a fellow who had a whole band playing him to sleep every night...